# When are throw(error) and return(value) useful in javascript iterators?

Tags: javascript, iterator, redux-saga

In javascript, iterators are allowed to have `throw(error)` and `return(value)` methods. `return(value)` gives the iterator a chance to see `value`, and is expected to return `{value: value, done: true}`. `throw(error)` gives the iterator a chance to see and potentially catch the error. If the error is caught, `throw` should return the next value. If the exception is not caught, it should be equivalent to `return(undefined)`. Here's an example of these mechanics in action:

```js
function* test() {
    try {
    yield 1;
  } catch(e) {}
  const fromConsumer = yield 2;
  yield fromConsumer;
  // I know no way to access the value passed to return in a generator
}

const iter = test()[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.throw(new Error('catch me')));
console.log(iter.next(9));
console.log(iter.next());
console.log(iter.return(0));
```

(Same thing as a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eqho5xc4/))

My question is: Why? Does anyone have a defensible use case for this reversal of control API for iterators? Under what conditions does it actually make sense for an iterator to handle an error incurred while consuming it? When would you want to pass a value to return given that it is certain to end the iterator and can't further influence the behavior of the iterator API?

I'll say that the one use case I'm aware of is redux-saga, where they have leveraged the inversion of control API of iterators seemingly as a poor man's async/await. If someone is familiar with design or usage of that tool, are there other benefits to their choice?

Comment: I don't have time to post a proper answer about this, and suspect some will say the question is too open-ended or opinion-based for SO (what qualifies as a "defensible" use case?), but: Look into *coroutines*. While iterators are allowed to have `return` and `throw`, it's really generators where they get useful. With generators, you can build coroutines. Coroutines are about more than being "a poor man's `async`/`await`."

Comment: _"Typically callers of these methods should check for their existence before invoking them. Certain ECMAScript language features including `for-of`, `yield*`, and array destructuring call these methods after performing an existence check. Most ECMAScript library functions that accept Iterable objects as arguments also conditionally call them."_ (Source: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-54)

Comment: Discussions on the redux saga issues board are somewhat enlightening too. They make the point that unlike async/await, it is possible to have synchronous execution (and as mentioned in another answer, early return).

Comment: Generator `finally` blocks are only guaranteed to run if a generator is *closed*, but not if it is merely garbage collected. `return` closes a generator, and before `return` was added, `throw` was your only explicit option for closing (and it is still your only option to tell a generator about an *exceptional* error/circumstances which it might want to handle and is distinct from a non-exceptional sending of a value in). You can also close a generator by doing a `for(... in generator)` loop on it, but `for(const unused in generator) break` is way less clear than `generator.return()`.

Answer (score 1):

First, not all iterators have return and throw. The only thing that an iterator needs to have is `next`. But it's true that the iterators created by generator functions have `return` and `throw`.

> I'll say that the one use case I'm aware of is redux-saga, where they have leveraged the inversion of control API of iterators seemingly as a poor man's async/await.

I'd say that's backwards. Generators aren't a poor version of async/await; async/await is narrow use of generators. In fact, the old equivalents of async/await were literally implemented using generators, as found in libraries like [co](https://github.com/tj/co). Now that async/await is part of the core language, i don't know if the underlying c++ code is literally using generators, but historically and conceptually it's an outgrowth of generators that's tied to the narrow case of resolving promises.

With a library like redux-saga, not only can you get await-like syntax, but you also have support for more complicated things such as task cancellation, which is something async/await cannot do. Task cancellation depends on the `return` method to work. Error handling is also supported, which is made possible by the `throw` method.

So generators are are a very broad tool which, among other things, can be used to model asynchronous behaviors. Because they're broad, they come with a set of functions which are able to model more than just iteration. I think of generators as not just a way to iterate things, but to have a two way conversation between two pieces of code. Among the things you might want to communicate is "there's a problem" or "we're done here", which is what throw and return are for.

> When would you want to pass a value to return given that it is certain to end the iterator and can't further influence the behavior of the iterator API?

Actually, it can still influence it. If the generator uses try/finally, `.return()` will send the generator into the finally block, where it can run as much code as it wants. The generator can even yield while in this finally block, with all the same behaviors it had before the finally block. Continuing with redux saga as an example, this feature of generators is used to support rolling back in the case of cancellation

```
function* exampleSaga() {
  try {
    // start working on something, with at least one yield
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      // roll back
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's just returning being useful though, not returning a value.

Comment: You're correct, i was just showing that its not certain to end the iterator and doesn't prevent further influence. If you wanted the value to matter, you'd have to write a custom iterator not using a generator function, since generator functions ignore the value passed into `return`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with so far:

Writing code as a generator manipulated by a coroutine offers these advantages over using async/await to interact with remote code:

1. There are three potential feedback paths the coroutine can use on the generator: `yield`, `throw`, and `return` instead of just `resolve` and `reject`. `return` in this case represents on option not available with vanilla promises, which is cancellation.
2. Unlike async/await, there is no requirement that transferring control flow will result in asynchronicity. This allows the coroutine to choose whether control continues synchronously or asynchronously, and allows it to inspect generated values and use them immediately if they are not promises.

And finally, as to when it is suitable for a generator to catch errors from a consumer, the answer is: when the consumer is a coroutine which encounters an error while doing what the generator directed it to do, in which case the generator, being the source of the error-causing action should also understand how to handle it.